# Apache/Mod_rewrite - Ignore question mark in URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Seemingly simple question, but I've searched and searched and found answers to pretty much every related question BUT this one ...

So a question mark designates the beginning of the query string. What I want to do is basically tell Apache to not treat a question mark as being special in this way, and to just pretend it's not there.

So I think what I really want to do is just rewrite this:

http://www.somesite.com/whatever/?query_string

to this:

http://www.somesite.com/whatever/query_string

Basically just strip out the ? and pretend it was never there.

I swear I've spent at least 2 hours trying to figure this out. I don't know if I'm having a major brain fart or what, but can someone help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(whatever/)$ $1%{QUERY_STRING}
```